# adding cancel button to cancel window open

Tags: javascript, extjs

```
var messagebox = Ext.widget("messagebox", {
  target: grid,
  progressMessage: "Loading"
});
```

Above message box is showing loading progress bar when download button is pressed. I need to add a cancel button to cancel the below popup window from executing. Can some one please help me cancel below popup window?

```
var win = new Ext.Window({
  title: "popup",
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
  layout: "fit",
  items: [
    {
      xtype: "component",
      autoEl: {
        tag: "popup",
        src: "www.google.com"
      }
    }
  ],
  listeners: {
    show: function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        popup.close();
      }, 2000);
    }
  }
}).show();
```

Comment: What toolkit and version are you using?

Comment: Pretty sure it is classic ... modern would use `Ext.Dialog`

Answer (score 0):

How about: `win.close()`

```
var win = new Ext.Window({
  title: "popup",
  // rest of the code
}).show();

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  win.close()
})
```

Comment: I am trying to add/bind a cancel button to the Ext.widget message box. Upon clicking it the window should close. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: can u add sample

Answer (score 0):

Window has `closable` config:

```
const win = new Ext.Window({
  title: "popup",
  closable: true
  // ...
});
```

You should also look at the `closeAction` config, which can either be `close` or `hide`. The former destroys the window, the latter just hides it from view, but keeps the component around.